# Is it possible to specify non-CIDR range in NFS (like 192.168.1.21-192.168.1.152)

Tags: rhel, nfs

Is it possible to specify non-CIDR range in NFS (like 192.168.1.21-192.168.1.152)?

The range I want to use can't be converted to 1 CIDR, it would need to be:

```
192.168.1.21/32
192.168.1.22/31
192.168.1.24/29
192.168.1.32/27
192.168.1.64/26
192.168.1.128/28
192.168.1.144/29
192.168.1.152/32
```

Which isn't very helpful

Comment: And pls don't tell me that network design is bad. It is with no doubts, but it's not in my powers to do anything about that...

Answer (score 1):

In `/etc/exports`? According to the [Red Hat documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/nfs-serverconfig.html#s2-nfs-hostname-formats), it doesn't seem like you could use an IP address range. Only power-of-two blocks, or DNS name matches. If the hosts in question have common hostname format, and you don't mind relying on the name server, that might be easiest.

Another choice would be to let the export be open to a wider range, but limit actual connections with `iptables`. [The `iprange` module](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html) would be able to specify a range of IP addresses to match, with `iptables -m iprange --src-range 192.168.1.21-192.168.1.152`.